# Operating on a file with overly long name

Tags: string, bash, environment-variables, command-line-interface

When I set up the ProtonMail Bridge CLI, it generated a hierarchy in my `.password-store` where the top level is called `protonmail-credentials`. This contains a subfolder where the name is a gibberish string enclosed in single quotes with--according to `wc -c`--153 characters. The name of the item under this is itself a 93-character string.

I would like to be able to operate on this item with `pass`, but wildcards apparently don't work for paths in `pass`, and dealing with such absurdly long strings which differ from setup to setup by typing everything out is not at all viable.

I am able to isolate the subfolder name with `ls -1 .password-store/protonmail-credentials`, which gives me the string beginning `'cHJv` and continuing onward. I thought I could assign this to an environment variable with `export $LONGDIRNAME=$(ls -1 .password-store/protonmail-credentials)`, but bash throws a 'not a valid identifier' error and thinks I'm trying to set the variable to a string beginning `=cHJv. I do not know why it is adding a backtick and equals sign to the string before attempting to set the variable.

Renaming either of these breaks ProtonMail Bridge's functionality, so `mv` is not an option either. What should I do with these strings to make the usable in `pass`?

Comment: You're getting "not a valid identifier" because of the dollar sign here: `$LONGDIRNAME`. That command should be `export LONGDIRNAME=$(...)`

Comment: Have you considered using a symlink?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.